# If the string draw in View‘s SubView?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm a new programer in iPhone and also not native speak english. I was confused in draw:rect. 
The question is: when I have a view A and a A's subview B,the B's draw:rect is :
[(A *)self.superview draw:rect],then I draw some string in A's draw:rect. when I change the B's frame the string is moved, so if it means the string draw in the subview B?
thanks for answer my question.
The code in class B:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  [(MyView *)self.superview drawMyRect:rect];
}
```

The code in class A:

```
-(void)drawMyRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSString *s = @"test view @_@";
    [s drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect  b = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    b.origin.x += _offsetRect.origin.x;
    b.origin.y += _offsetRect.origin.y;
    b.size.height -= _offsetRect.size.height;
    b.size.width -= _offsetRect.size.width;
    [_theSubView setFrame:b];
    [_theSubView setNeedsDisplay];
    _offsetRect = CGRectZero;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: Can you put some code? For example both draw:rect]?

Comment: You should not be calling drawRect: (draw:rect does not exist) on an instance of any class. Please read some documentation. Also, please post some code.